# Last child forked will not die

Tags: c, linux, pipe, kill, children

I have the main process forking two times and thus creating two children. The two children are piped with each other like this:

```
ls | more
```

Now the problem is that the second child never dies. Why is that? When does the last child in a pipe die really?

Removing one *wait()* call shows the expected result of `ls | more` but gives some further weird behaviours(stuck terminal etc).

Here is my code:

```
int main(){
  printf("[%d] main\n", getpid());
  int pip[2], i;
  pipe(pip);

  /* CHILDREN*/
  for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    if (fork()==0){

      /* First child */
      if (i==0){
        printf("[%d] child1\n", getpid());
        close(1); dup(pip[1]);
        close(pip[0]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", NULL);}

      /* Second child */
      if (i==1){
        printf("[%d] child2\n", getpid());
        close(0); dup(pip[0]);
        close(pip[1]);
        execlp("more", "more", NULL);}
    }  
  }
  wait(NULL);  // wait for first child
  wait(NULL);  // wait for second child
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The title of this question sounds very violent.

Comment: @Marlon haha didn't see it like that until now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The read end of the pipe won't get an EOF mark until the write end has been closed by all its users. The parent of both children still has both ends of the pipe open, so `more` doesn't see an EOF (a return of 0 from `read()`), and keeps waiting for more input.

Answer (score 0):

Check with `ps axw` that it's really the `more` that isn't dying.  Then read the man page for [wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait).  Look at the returned status for `wait`.

(Hint: look at what causes a 'zombie' process.  I don't think the waits are doing what you think they are.)

Comment: Have done that also with "ps aux | grep more". I can see the second child alive and the prompt just hangs(waiting for the child).